# Cannot run 2nd command on windows command line

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm

I am running a node.js application with scripts as given below:

```
"scripts":{
"dev": "npm run dev-client & nodemon index.js",
"dev-client" :"npm run clean && parcel client/src/index.html --out-dir client/dist",
    "clean": "rmdir /s /q .cache \"client/dist\" && mkdir \"client/dist\""
}
```

so when I run `npm run dev`

just the `dev-client` part is run and **not** the `nodemon index.js` as attached below.

```
PS E:\blockchain\cryptochain> npm run dev

> cryptochain@1.0.0 dev E:\blockchain\cryptochain
> npm run dev-client & nodemon index.js


> cryptochain@1.0.0 dev-client E:\blockchain\cryptochain
> npm run clean && parcel client/src/index.html --out-dir client/dist


> cryptochain@1.0.0 clean E:\blockchain\cryptochain
> rmdir /s /q .cache "client/dist" && mkdir "client/dist"

Server running at http://localhost:1234
√  Built in 13.18s.
```

The `nodemon index.js` script is supposed to start a server at localhost:3000

PS: This works well on the linux environment but doesn't on windows

Comment: Maybe use && instead of &?

Comment: && means run 2nd command only if the 1st is completed which is not possible since the live server will keep listening.
   
& means run both commands in order (this works fine in linux env)

Comment: The syntax depends on your shell. bash uses `&` for background execution, but cmd.exe for example uses `&` like bash's `;` for unconditional _serial_ execution. You better use a node script to run those things instead of relying on shells so that it can work platform-independently.